# XAMP/WAMP server with Laravel Framework 5.8.11 gives server error 500

Tags: apache-http-server, xampp, wamp

1. error 500 is coming after composer update on root folder of project.
2. Error was coming in WAMP (tried cleaning up .htaccess file, allowed httpd.conf's Directory permission and all suggestion received in the forum). not able to fix the issue thats why tried in XAMP but same problem.
3. created virtual host for the laravel and localhost.
4. localhost is working perfectly fine but laravel public folder link is throwing 500 error.

Please help.

Comment: Check the error logs in storage/logs

Comment: Thanks Robert..checking storage/logs definitely helped me, key was not set in my app, ran following command: php artisan key:generate
php artisan config:cache
php artisan serve

Comment: I think that was my issue as well.